# What is wrong with my simple code in importing a module?

Tags: class, module

I have written the simple code below to check how to import a module:

```
#check.py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Name"

    def func1(self):
        print(self.name)
```

=============================

```
import check

check.Test.func1()


but when I run this simple code, I get the error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mf0016/Desktop/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On-Second-Edition-master/check_1.py", line 4, in <module>
    check.Test.func1()
TypeError: func1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Could you please help me to understand my mistake

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate but I don't understand your comment. Could you please explain a little more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python automatically "binds" the first argument of a method that was declared in a class, to the instance of an object it was called on. So you have to instantiate your Test class (i.e., create a new `Test`) in order to get this behavior. You can also just call it directly, but in this case, you have to provide the value of `self` yourself (heh).

```py
import check

t = check.Test() # create a new one
t.func1() #this works, because t is now bound to self 

check.Test.func1(t) # this also works; you're binding it manually.
```

Comment: Thanks, Oliver Richardson! It was halpful

Comment: Glad to hear!  Also, once you're satisfied you should accept an answer, so that (1) you and the person who wrote the answer both get the gratification of imaginary internet points, and (2) to avoid drawing attention away from other unanswered questions.